# Convert fortran-iso-c-binding real variable to real

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

With fortran-iso-c-binding I can interface C functions and get variables of types like

```
real(c_float)
integer(c_int)
```

But in the rest of a program I would like to use basic types (simply because I do not want to replace many real variables with `real(c_float)` variables just because of one interface function)

Is there a safe, platform/compiler independent and reliable way how to cast fortran-iso-c-binding types back to fortran (primitive) types? [equivalent to REAL()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/REAL.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REAL intrinsic is what you want.  Or equivalently, simple assignment.

```
REAL(C_FLOAT) :: r_c
REAL :: r_default
r_default = r_c
```

If the value being converted is out of range for the destination kind, your program is non-conforming.

Comment: [REAL intrinsic documentation - section Arguments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/REAL.html) states that argument "Shall be INTEGER, REAL, or COMPLEX".

Comment: An object declared `REAL(C_FLOAT) :: x` is an object of type REAL.  You can use the REAL intrinsic function to convert between different kinds of real.  Assignment does the equivalent thing, by definition.